# Add a product to wishlist of Customers in particular group

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist, customer-group

I am trying to add a product to wishlist of all customer in a particular group.

**Currently I have added products to a particular customer's wishlist.**

That I have to add to a particular group of customers.

Can anyone guide me regarding this ?

Comment: Do you want it programmatically or something from backend ?

Comment: I want to do it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update your class constructor like this:

```
  protected $_wishlistRepository;

  protected $_productRepository;

  protected $_customerFactory;

  public function __construct(
      ...
      \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistRepository,
      \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
      \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
  ) {
      $this->_wishlistRepository= $wishlistRepository;
      $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
      $this->_customerFactory = $productRepository;
      ...
  }
```

Then in you can do the following,

```
  /** set customer group id in filter of customer collection**/
  $customerCollection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('group_id', 4);
  foreach($customerCollection as $customer)
  {
      $customerId = $customer->getCustomerId(); 
      try {
          $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
      } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
          $product = null;
      }

      $wishlist = $this->_wishlistRepository->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);

      $wishlist->addNewItem($product);
      $wishlist->save();
  }
```